# Create a hash of a method in python source

Tags: python, methods, hashcode

I am facing a problem where we need to keep track of certain python methods in third party code to see if they have changed.

We can't hash the entire file, because there may be all sorts of unrelated changes.

So, I have no problem writing a process which, when called, will provide a file name with path, and a class name, and a method name.

I need some pointers how to read just that method out - obviously the line numbers cant be relied upon - and then I can create a hash and store it.

I cannot seem to find any way to "locate method X in class Y in a python .py file"

Note this source being scanned may not even be pathed to, so I cannot find or analyise the classes from within - I need a function which can analyse the source without opening it (it is a library of files which I have not even pathed to).

Comment: I can't understand the "analyse the source without opening it" part.

Comment: Mainly, I want to avoid loading the modules - it is third party code - it has hundreds of methods and classes - and may even have bugs or might be not executable - but I know it is python (even if it is python with bugs that stop it executing) - and I just need to know if any of a particular method in a particular class has changed.

Comment: This was an interesting question-- can I ask what the reasoning was for this functionality?  seems like for creating a report for regularly auditing 3rd party libraries and the changes that happen within them?

Comment: @OuyangZe  We are using lots of "library" code, which we can inherit.  But occasionally, the library method needs a complete override to insert hooks so that we can extend it cleanly.

We need to know if the library code we are extending has changed, so we can update our override.

At the top of our "override" py files, which we strictly set with one method override only per file, we have a generic method which contains a commented set of the code as it was when we override it, and paths to the library version.  If the hashes mismatch, then we need to update our override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I explored your options and had success, generally.

In the end, though, because the environment we are executing in is a heavily modified environment (it is the Odoo framework) I encountered issues like modified loader, which complained about the way it was specced, and so on.

Ultimately, I anticipated these problems, which is why I was looking for a solution which did not load the file, as a module.

This is what I ended up with...

```
import ast

def create_hash(self, fname, class_name, method_name):
    source_item = False
    next_item = False
    with open(fname) as f:
        tree = ast.parse(f.read(), filename=fname)
        for item in tree.body:
            if source_item:
                next_item = item
                break
            if item.__class__.__name__ == 'ClassDef' and item.name == class_name:
                for subitem in item.body:
                    if source_item:
                        next_item = subitem
                        break
                    if subitem.__class__.__name__ == 'FunctionDef' and subitem.name == method_name:
                        source_item = subitem
                if next_item:
                    break

    assert source_item, 'Unable to find method %s on %s' % (method_name, class_name)
    from_line = min(
        [source_item.lineno]
        + (hasattr(source_item, 'decorator_list') and [d.lineno for d in source_item.decorator_list] or [])
    )
    to_line = next_item and min(
        [next_item.lineno]
        + (hasattr(next_item, 'decorator_list') and [d.lineno for d in next_item.decorator_list] or [])
    ) - 1 or False

    with open(fname) as f:
        if to_line:
            code = lines[from_line - 1:to_line]
        else:
            code = lines[from_line - 1:]

    hash_object = hashlib.sha256(bytes(''.join(code), 'utf-8'))
    hexdigest = hash_object.hexdigest()
    return hexdigest
```

Edit:

It seems that different versions of AST change the function's "lineno" - in older versions it was the min of the def and the decorator - in newer versions it is the line of the def.

So I have changed the code to allow for both implementations....

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) to import the method, and [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module to hash the byte code of the function :

```py
import dis
import hashlib

module = __import__('my_package.my_module', fromlist=['Klass'])

method_code = dis.Bytecode(module.Klass.method).codeobj.co_code
hasher = hashlib.sha256()
hasher.update(method_code)
h = hasher.digest()
```

For instance with the `Request` class of the mole `requests`:

```py
>>> requests = __import__('requests', fromlist=['Request'])
>>> method_code = dis.Bytecode(requests.Request.prepare).codeobj.co_code
>>> hasher = hashlib.sha256()
>>> hasher.update(method_code)
>>> hasher.digest()
b'\xd8\x03\x04\xdfA8\x90L[\x8b\x97\xae~\xe7\x90\x91B^%+\xc2\x99\x14\xbf\xe2\xcaB\x8a\xe6\xa5\x96\xc4'
```

Comment: If you run it twice (from different Python sessions), you'll get different results.

Comment: @bereal You're right, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the body of method (using `inspect`), and then hash it (using `hashlib`).

Assuming you want to get hash for method `test_method` from `test_class` in file `test.py`, which looks like this:
**test.py**

```py
class test_class:
    def test_method():
        return 'test'
```

You should do something like this:

```py
import os
import inspect
import hashlib
import importlib.util

def get_hash(file_path, class_name, method_name):
    try:
        # get full path
        if not file_path.startswith('/'):
            file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_path)
        # get method body
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(class_name, file_path)
        foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
        my_class = getattr(foo, class_name)
        my_method = getattr(my_class, method_name)
        body = inspect.getsource(my_method)
        # hash
        hash_object = hashlib.sha256(bytes(body, 'utf-8'))
        return hash_object.hexdigest()
        
    except (AttributeError, FileNotFoundError, TypeError):
        return ''

print(get_hash('test.py', 'test_class', 'test_method'))
# 1b7c4367c925d6891313b671a41600fc581854513a10c704b32441afea01d591
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer-- but won't work if you're looking to just check whether the behavior of the function has changed.  For example, if one changes the docstring within the method, or adds a comment, you'll get a different hash.  Probably looking for something like what [dhall](https://dhall-lang.org/#) offers for behavior-preserving hashing... something I'm not even sure if python would be able to support.  the above responses seem like good general purpose cases tho.